# dopar% and %foreach% failed to work for gmapsdistance

Tags: r, for-loop, google-maps, parallel.foreach, doparallel

I am currently trying to apply parallelization with the `gmapsdistance` package (`driving mode = bicycling`) to speed up the computation of the `for` loop that contains `1` origin and `100` destinations **per each value of X**. I have 500 values of X corresponding to 500 pairs of `1` origin and `100` destinations, and I need to compute the `gmapsdistance` for these 500 pairs **sequentially**. If I apply the `gmapsdistance` function directly to all 500 pairs of `1` origin and `100` destination, I often hit the limit imposed by Google Maps API. Thus, I decided to compute `gmapsdistance` of each individual set of `1` origin and `100` destinations using `for` loop. Based on my initial inspection, it seems to me that breaking down the $100$ destinations by batches of 40-60 elements would be the best way to speed it up.

**Question:** How do I correctly apply `foreach` and `%dopar%` to speed up the computation of `1` origin and `100` destinations? I tried with the following code but the %foreach% seems not to do its job of computing the `gmapsdistance` at all.

```
origin <- "30.458788+-91.66276"
destination

n.dest <- length(destination)
res <- list()

library(doParallel)
ncores <- detectCores()-8
registerDoParallel(ncores)
result <- foreach(j=seq(n.dest/40+1), .combine = rbind, 
                .packages = "gmapsdistance", .multicombine = TRUE) 
       %dopar% {
         j.start <- (j-1)*40+1
         j.end <- min(j*40, n.dest)
         dest.tmp <- destination[j.start:j.end]
          matrix <- gmapsdistance(origin, destination, 
                                  mode='bicycling',  shape="long", 
                                  key = [key to Google Maps API here])
      #if(length(dest.tmp)==1){
      #  res[[j]] <- (matrix$Distance)/1609
      #} else {
      #         matrix$Distance$Distance <- #as.vector(matrix$Distance$Distance)/1609 
      #         res[[j]] <- matrix$Distance$Distance
      }

  }
```

Sample Data

```
destination <-
"31.458788+-90.66276"
"32.458788+-90.66276"
"30.457391+-90.637622"
"31.40022+-91.007789"
"32.400216+-91.007899"
"31.745092+-90.72207"
"30.355628+-91.039009"
"32.755678+-90.715828"
"31.752829+-90.724454"
"32.758509+-90.715734"
"30.758526+-90.715734"
"31.762113+-90.71588"
"31.34873+-91.043439"
"30.527764+-90.21993"
"31.525427+-90.215216"
"32.526959+-90.213706"
"30.504474+-90.183939"
"31.875694+-90.393612"
"30.867884+-90.394896"
"31.865573+-90.393505"
"30.486356+-89.759238"
"32.189036+-90.575873"
"31.188247+-90.581814"
"31.785027+-89.843494"
"32.78316+-89.831685"
"30.78316+-89.831685"
"31.765321+-89.824013"
"32.765321+-89.824013"
"30.605845+-90.067735"
"31.605022+-90.067732"
"30.603925+-90.067727"
"31.599866+-90.067711"
"31.599554+-90.067711"
"31.59933+-90.067711"
"32.88156+-91.48726"
"31.17727+-91.913525"
"30.476405+-90.153457"
"31.322707+-89.950904"
"32.621621+-91.80243"
"30.624892+-91.802716"
"31.633465+-91.801092"
"31.638366+-91.802947"
"31.309983+-89.927821"
"30.309662+-89.927826"
"30.03933+-89.579129"
"31.31023+-89.923957"
"31.309487+-89.923367"
"30.309488+-89.923119"
"31.045959+-89.573218"
"30.517189+-90.099222"
"30.441837+-90.149984"
"30.442301+-90.150707"
"30.440868+-90.149794"
"32.312126+-89.91667"
"30.439829+-90.146798"
"30.34343+-90.83843"
"30.3423+-90.837489"
"30.340156+-90.83728"
"30.343552+-90.84245"
"30.349831+-90.881005"
"30.341989+-90.840575"
"30.341655+-90.841115"
"30.343312+-90.848024"
"30.3405+-90.84298"
"30.432235+-90.140964"
"30.50413+-90.092005"
"30.34301+-90.850283"
"30.329542+-90.325884"
"30.328089+-90.325728"
"30.328336+-90.325734"
"30.428608+-90.153354"
"30.328893+-90.323734"
"30.329036+-90.323154"
"30.324194+-90.325706"
"30.329507+-90.317416"
"30.325438+-90.328082"
"30.385365+-90.17449"
"30.3217+-90.319121"
"30.385387+-90.173534"
"30.409225+-90.140713"
"30.409225+-90.140713"
"30.408096+-90.1407"
"31.408096+-90.1407"
"30.403206+-90.142447"
"30.399693+-90.143573"
"30.40238+-90.137045"
"30.402334+-90.137005"
"30.395251+-90.145992"
"30.318924+-90.873704"
"30.317151+-90.874869"
"30.315461+-90.879247"
"30.395372+-90.142445"
"30.383176+-90.147925"
"30.380337+-90.149091"
"30.389491+-90.145018"
"30.333701+-90.176533"
"30.303498+-90.889794"
"30.372756+-90.14738"
"30.300538+-90.189769"
"30.290752+-90.264155"
"30.301205+-90.185661"
```

Comment: There is a closing `}` missing. Learn how a `foreach` loop works. The loop body needs a "return" value. `res` doesnot exist when the loop is executed and thus subsetting it results in an error.

Comment: @Roland: Thank you for your comment. I edited my code (sorry I messed up copy-paste). I tried running the above code, but the `foreach` loop still does not compute the `gmapsdistance`. Could you help assist?

Comment: I studied it, and then how does it help with my problem Sir?

Comment: Can anyone please give me some more concrete help?

Comment: Look, start simple. Create a simple parallelized `foreach` loop that works. Once you grasp the principle, it should be easy.

Comment: I did not tell you to use `return()`. The last statement of the loop body is returned, so don't put `Sys.sleep(1)` there.

Comment: And, again, `res` doesnot exist within the scope of the loop body.

Comment: wait a minute...why did `res` does not exist within the scope of the loop body? I put it right before closing the 2nd bracket `}`, so shouldn't it exist?

Comment: So I commented out all the lines involving `if` part, and even in that case, I would need to have `return(matrix)`. Otherwise, I get a the same weird output on each `result.1`, `result.2`, etc as  `dataframe, 3` , `dataframe, 3`, `dataframe, 3`. Do you know why?